# Google charts not showing axis labels

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This is not for the image charts. 
 I have the following code that generates the right chart but the labels don't show. The chart div is in an other div that is used as a tab on my page. 
 When I run the function when the tab containing the chart is not selected, the chart appears with no labels. When I run the function with the tab selected, the labels appear.

```
  drawChart()
  }

   function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Weeks');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Indice');

    data.addRows(arrIndice1);

    var options = {
      width:"900",
      height:"500",
      legend: "none",
      title: 'Indice 1',
      chartArea:{left:20,top:50,width:"85%",height:"75%"} 
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: with firebug or IE developer tools check if you have another div over "tab div". Is it possible that part of tab div is hidden when it is not selected?

Answer (score 2):

chartArea options seem to cover the axis labels when they increase the chart size. Try removing the `chartArea:{left:20,top:50,width:"85%",height:"75%"}` part.