# Issue with multiple google chart on single page - labels are shown with first chart only

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

I am having the following strange behavior with multiple Google charts (3 in total) on same page and I am unable to resolve it yet. Let me explain.

Here are the screenshots:

**First chart**
[image]

**Rendered script output for the above chart (page source view):**

```
<div id="chart_div_stella-york-dream-big"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_chart_div_stella_york_dream_big);

        function drawChart_chart_div_stella_york_dream_big() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ["Month", "Points", { role: "style" } ],
                ["Jan", 39, "#4a7dae"],["Feb", 15.5, "#4a7dae"],["Mar", 19.5, "#4a7dae"],["Apr", 0, "#4a7dae"],["May", 0, "#4a7dae"],["Jun", 0, "#4a7dae"],            
            ]);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
                { calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation" },
                2]);

            var options = {
                title: "",
                width: "100%",
                height: 300,
                bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
                legend: { position: "none" },
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_div_stella-york-dream-big"));
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
    </script>
```

**Second chart**
[image]

**Rendered script output for the above chart (page source view):**

```
<div id="chart_div_essense-dream-big"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_chart_div_essense_dream_big);

        function drawChart_chart_div_essense_dream_big() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ["Month", "Points", { role: "style" } ],
                ["Jan", 31, "#4a7dae"],["Feb", 35.5, "#4a7dae"],["Mar", 22, "#4a7dae"],["Apr", 0, "#4a7dae"],["May", 0, "#4a7dae"],["Jun", 0, "#4a7dae"],            
            ]);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
                { calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation" },
                2]);

            var options = {
                title: "",
                width: "100%",
                height: 300,
                bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
                legend: { position: "none" },
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_div_essense-dream-big"));
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
    </script>
```

**Third chart**
[image]

**Rendered script output for the above chart (page source view):**

```
<div id="chart_div_martina-liana-dream-big"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_chart_div_martina_liana_dream_big);

        function drawChart_chart_div_martina_liana_dream_big() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ["Month", "Points", { role: "style" } ],
                ["Jan", 19, "#4a7dae"],["Feb", 14, "#4a7dae"],["Mar", 6, "#4a7dae"],["Apr", 0, "#4a7dae"],["May", 0, "#4a7dae"],["Jun", 0, "#4a7dae"],            
            ]);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
                { calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation" },
                2]);

            var options = {
                title: "",
                width: "100%",
                height: 300,
                bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
                legend: { position: "none" },
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_div_martina-liana-dream-big"));
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
    </script>
```

In the **First Chart** I have the labels at the left (0-40) and the zero values are also displayed for months Apr-Jun.

But they both are not being rendered in **Second** and **Third** charts.

I have used this PHP function to render the script on page:

```
function render_chart_script( $container, $model, $chart_title = '' ) { ?>
    <?php
    ob_start();
    $function_suffix = str_replace( "-", "_", $container );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_<?php echo $function_suffix; ?>);

        function drawChart_<?php echo $function_suffix; ?>() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ["Month", "Points", { role: "style" }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
                <?php
                foreach( $model as $key => $value ) {
                    echo '["' . get_short_month_name( $key ) . '", ' . $model[$key] . ', "#4a7dae", ' . $model[$key] . '],';
                }?>

            ]);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
                { calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation" },
                2]);

            var options = {
                title: "<?php echo $chart_title; ?>",
                width: "100%",
                height: 300,
                bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
                legend: { position: "none" },
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("<?php echo $container; ?>"));
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
    </script>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Which is outputting the scripts correctly when I see the page source. To avoid conflict I have made the function names dynamic as well.

I compared three script outputs and did not find any difference in structures and definitions. What could be the possible issue?

I am referring to [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts#draw-multiple-charts-on-one-page).

**UPDATE:**

I took a closer look in Inspector and found the following block of code is only appearing for the first chart. When I add the same block inside inspector tool, the labels have come up!

```
<g><text text-anchor="end" x="60" y="246.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0</text></g>
<g><text text-anchor="end" x="60" y="200.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">10</text></g>
<g><text text-anchor="end" x="60" y="154.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">20</text></g>
<g><text text-anchor="end" x="60" y="108.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">30</text></g>
<g><text text-anchor="end" x="60" y="62.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">40</text></g>
```

The above code is responsible for rendering the Y-axis values. Here ismy observation:

[image]

Comment: If you swap the data out (swap chart 1 for chart 2) does the new chart 1 (which was previously chart 2) display the labels correctly?

Comment: Good point! I didn't think of testing this way. I will check soon and get back to you.

Comment: Just checked the way you suggested. It is always only the first one with labels!

Comment: You can try messing around with the chartArea: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2693 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486908/google-charts-not-showing-axis-labels

Comment: @BrettGregson forgot to mention in my last comment. It would be great if you please check the UPDATE section of original post if you haven't already :)

Comment: Thank you! Changing "current" to "45" fixed the Y-axis issue. However, columns with 0 are displaying on the first chart only. I have posted recent issue in Github thread. https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2693#issuecomment-541033939

Comment: Glad you managed to get it just about working, good luck with the rest. Maybe make a new question on SO as well with the new issue

Comment: Yes! I would do that.

Comment: are all the charts visible when drawn, or do you have to select a tab or something to see the second and third charts? if so, you need to wait until the chart containers are visible, before drawing for the first time. this is a known issue, if the containers are hidden, the code cannot properly calculate the placement of all the elements...

Comment: @WhiteHat you are right. I have charts in different tabs. But the content is already rendered including chart data. Not using AJAX to draw chart when container is visible.  Just the container is visible when a tab is clicked. By drawing chart do you mean it is only drawn when the container is visible? If yes and still it is a known issue, is there a fix for that yet?

Comment: just need to wait until the tab is shown before calling `draw`, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558808/5090771)...